# .Net Maui unable to deploy on Android Emulator Using Visual Studio for Mac Preview 17.4

Tags: visual-studio, maui, .net-maui

I'm building a cross platform line of business app on .Net Maui.  Everything was working (mostly) fine(ish) until today when I updated the .net core sdk from version 6.0.400-preview.22330.6 to 6.0.400.  **To my knowledge that is the only thing I have changed.**

Now any time I attempt to debug the app, the build succeeds however VS for Mac displays an error message after "Deploying to Device".  The Error message is: "**Cannot execute "Users/xxxx/src/Mobile/bin/Debug/net6.0-android/Mobile.dll**

I can't tell what is causing it.  It appears like the all the steps succeed in the "Deploying to Device" window. Zero Errors and Zero warnings.

I have noticed that most of the targets are skipped because "all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files".  Thusly, **I have cleaned both from the command line and in VS for Mac with no luck.**

Finally, I can run the application in the emulator if I use the command:

```
dotnet build -t:Run -f:net6.0-android
```

UPDATE:

I pulled up the VS for Mac Logs and found this:

```
ERROR [2022-08-15 15:48:19Z]: Error loading android manifest '/Users/xxxx/src/Mobile/obj/Debug/net6.0-android/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'versions')
   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidAppManifest.Load(String filename, AndroidVersions versions) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/external/androidtools/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Xamarin.Android.Tools.AndroidSdk/AndroidAppManifest.cs:line 84
   at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.ProjectSystem.AndroidApplicationManifest..ctor(String manifestFile, AndroidProjectProperties projectProperties) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/ProjectSystem/PropertiesProviders/AndroidApplicationManifest.cs:line 13
   at MonoDevelop.MonoDroid.ProjectSystem.AndroidManifestCache.CreateNewManifest(String filename) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/ProjectSystem/PropertiesProviders/AndroidManifestCache.cs:line 33

INFO [2022-08-15 15:48:19Z]: Add-in loaded: DotNetCore.Debugger
INFO [2022-08-15 15:48:19Z]: Add-in loaded: MonoDevelop.Debugger.Soft.AspNet
ERROR [2022-08-15 15:48:19Z]: Cannot execute "/Users/xxxx/src/Mobile/bin/Debug/net6.0-android/Mobile.dll"
```

So for some reason it appears to be linked to the android manifest not being available in the obj folder.  I did check the folder and the manifest is indeed in that location.  However, I'm not certain if its a race condition or something that makes the file not there at the time the tooling attempts to load the manifest.

UPDATE 2:

I created a new app just to see if there was something wrong with my current app.  Same issue.  As requested here is the app manifest located in the **obj/Debug/net6.0-android** folder of the project.  I'm not certain this matters or not, but there **is not** an app manifest in the bin/Debug/net6.0-android folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
    This code was generated by a tool.
    It was generated from /Users/xxxx/src/NewTest/Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml
    Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    the contents are regenerated.
    -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" package="com.companyname.newtest" android:versionName="1.0">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:name="crc64035c0982af6367fe.MainApplication" android:label="NewTest" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <activity android:configChanges="density|orientation|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|screenSize|uiMode" android:theme="@style/Maui.SplashTheme" android:name="crc64035c0982af6367fe.MainActivity" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="crc6468b6408a11370c2f.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.newtest.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/microsoft_maui_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64e53d2f592022988e.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc640a8d9a12ddbf2cf2.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc640a8d9a12ddbf2cf2.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
    <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.companyname.newtest.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the original app manifest file located in the Platforms/Android directory of the project (the one visible in the solution explorer)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

UPDATE 3:

I just unpacked the signed app file from the Bin folder and got the contents out of that app manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:compileSdkVersion="31" android:compileSdkVersionCodename="12" package="com.companyname.newtest" platformBuildVersionCode="31" platformBuildVersionName="12">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" android:debuggable="true" android:extractNativeLibs="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:label="NewTest" android:name="crc64035c0982af6367fe.MainApplication" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="density|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode" android:exported="true" android:name="crc64035c0982af6367fe.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Maui.SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="crc6468b6408a11370c2f.WebAuthenticatorIntermediateActivity"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.newtest.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="microsoft.maui.essentials.fileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/microsoft_maui_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths"/>
        </provider>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc64e53d2f592022988e.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true" android:name="crc64ba438d8f48cf7e75.IntermediateActivity"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc640a8d9a12ddbf2cf2.BatteryBroadcastReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="crc640a8d9a12ddbf2cf2.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver"/>
        <service android:name="crc64396a3fe5f8138e3f.KeepAliveService"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.newtest.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.companyname.newtest.androidx-startup" android:exported="false" android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.emoji2.text.EmojiCompatInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
            <meta-data android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup"/>
        </provider>
        <uses-library android:name="androidx.window.extensions" android:required="false"/>
        <uses-library android:name="androidx.window.sidecar" android:required="false"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: According to the error messages, it seems there is something missed in your AndroidManifest.xml. Can you show about it?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT please see my Update 2.  I included both the obj (code generated) app manifest, as well as the project app manifest.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT - also see update 3. I unpacked the apk file and grabbed that xml

Comment: I can't check the xml in the bin folder, but your manifest file located in the Platforms/Android directory is same as mine. Everything seems right. Did you search about the parameter named versions in the `Load(String filename, AndroidVersions versions)`?